# How to extract records with a specific but shared attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute

My goal is to isolate the ID#s observed in Zone C and only Zone C (like IDs 2236 and 3007 in the attached table). There are records for which the same ID was observed in other zones besides Zone C, or was observed multiple times in Zone C.

How can I extract only those individuals who were observed in C and ONLY in C? Selecting by location is not what I need because some of the ID#s in C are also in other zones.  I have tried Select by Attribute and the Dissolve tool but I am not quite getting the right combination. Can someone point me in the right direction?  I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.

[image: clip of attribute table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution via the Field Calculator and a short python code.

1. First add a Field to your Table (in my example it is named test).
2. Next open the Field Calculator for your new Field.

   [image]
3. There you have to mark Python at the top and check the Show Codeblock
4. In the Codeblock/Pre Logic Script Code you post this Python Script(you must only edit "your_layer_name" and maybe the field name directly behind it):

`list = [ ]
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("your_layer_name", ["ID#", "Zone"])
for row in cursor:
    if row[1] != "C":
        list.append(row[0])
def calc(id):
    global list
    if id in list:
        return( 0)
    else:
        return(1)`

5. In the lower box you write the following (change ID# to the name of your id field):
   `calc(!ID#!)`
6. Now you can click on Ok. Every ID#, which has only Zone C has a 1 and every other row has now 0 in Field test.

   [image]
7. Just do now a Select by Attributes with `test = 1`

Hope this can help, if you have questions just ask.

Comment: Thank you!  However, I am sure your solution is correct but it is failing to execute on my end.  I am getting a syntax error: "Parsing error IndentationError: unexpected indent (line 3)"

Comment: I edited my post, it seems i made a mistake at the moment i copied the script.